# Paypal (buyer direct make payment to seller )

Tags: php, paypal

Is it possible to be the middle man for a Paypal transaction without having anything thing to do with the transaction (PayPal account wise). **Do it at localhost first.**

The buyer pays directly into the seller's account and my site verify's the purchase and redirect to the success pages.

**Example:**

Auction websites : 2 type of role (seller and buyer)

when the buyer bid the items successfully they able to make payment through paypal directly to seller.

it is possible to make it in localhost??

anyone can help me T.T